# Standard (and most practical) approach to storing large amounts of data to be read by a Java application

Tags: java, database

I am working with a database that is divided into a few dozen text files, each containing two columns and are 200 lines long.

Currently, I only load up one of the text files and read the data from it into two arrays. I could simply go through the handful of text files and load the data one after the other but I wanted to know what would be the approach to manage a "database" of this size and what would be the "standard" of the format of the database if it were to be included in the end application.

I could simply have a single text file that would hold all the data and would end up 250 000 lines long - while this would work, I just do not know better if it at all seems professional and practical. A much better approach would be if I could have a single file and then via code specify which table (the sub-text files are basically two column tables, hence a few dozens of them) I would like the data from to be read into two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a real database? 
You could use some in-memory-database.